# Projects Supporting "Data Sources" Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, datasource

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) says "The Show Data Sources command is only available in projects that support creating and working with data sources."  However, it does not say or give a list of which projects those are.  What *are* the projects that permit / use the "data sources" window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this other [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that has a more details on data sources and the type of projects where you would have access to them

Comment: That article certainly reveals all the possible data sources, but it does not say what projects have access to the "Data Sources" window.  For example, I created a "SQL Server 2005 Database Project."  When I select the VS "Data" menu drop-down, it does not have the "Show Data Sources" option that MSDN documentation claims is there.  Perhaps that makes sense, but I'm curious to know what the heuristic for which projects do or do not have access to that menu option.

Comment: It does make sense, a SQL Server 2005 Database Project has not that source because itself **is** the datasource. You'll see the datasources window on Windows Projects, Web Projects and all the projects that need to extract data from a data source.

Comment: I'll accept that heuristic, though I'd still wonder if there are projects that "need to extract data," and yet do not have access to datasource components.  I suppose, to add to the heuristic, that non-MS (custom) project types might have that shortcoming.

Comment: Update: An ASP.NET MVC project is an example of a project that "needs to extract data" but does not have a "data sources" window.  I suspect the better answer is this: the "data sources" window is available only for project types that have a (UI) designer surface (e.g. WPF, WebForms, ASP.NET).